# "Hostname match not found" error in firebase phone authentication(with ionic)

Tags: firebase, authentication, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to combine "firebase phone authentication" with ionic.

but, stuck in one question.

I keep getting **"Hostname match not found"** error from

```
.catch(function (error) { 
  console.log("error! : " +  error); 
});"
```

of login.ts(below)

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';

import firebase from 'firebase';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
   selector: 'page-login',
   templateUrl: 'login.html',
})

export class LoginPage {
  public recaptchaVerifier:firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public alertCtrl: AlertController) {}

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.recaptchaVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('recaptcha-
    container');
  }

  signIn(phoneNumber: number){
    const appVerifier = this.recaptchaVerifier;
    const phoneNumberString = "+" + phoneNumber;

    firebase.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumberString, appVerifier)
      .then( confirmationResult => {

        let prompt = this.alertCtrl.create({
        title: 'Enter the Confirmation code',
        inputs: [{ name: 'confirmationCode', placeholder: 'Confirmation Code' }],
        buttons: [
          { text: 'Cancel',
            handler: data => { console.log('Cancel clicked'); }
          },
          { text: 'Send',
            handler: data => {
               confirmationResult.confirm(data.confirmationCode)
                 .then(function (result) {

                 }).catch(function (error) {

                 });
            }
          }
        ]
     });
     prompt.present();
   })
   .catch(function (error) {
      console.log("error! : " +  error);           //   <------------The place that informs this error.
   });
 }
}
```

this error occurred shortly after reCAPTCHA solved

Why does this happen?

--Initializing Firebase

[image]

--login.html

[image]

Comment: are you getting country code along with `phoneNumber` from input field?

Comment: i inputted country code  with input field like this --> 8155555555(55555555 is my phone number). and I even fixed code like this  -->  const phoneNumberString = "+81-" + phoneNumber;

Comment: did you tried without hyphen `+81`

Comment: still doesn't work.....T T  "Hostname match not found" occur.....

Comment: are you doing this on localhost or any domain?

Comment: Did u find the solution?

Answer (score 78):

This error may occur when you host your app in no `ssl` certified domain. Then you have to whitelist your domain in firebase console.

Go to `Firebase Console -> Authentication -> sign-in-method -> Authorized Domains` and add your domain.

By default `localhost`and any `https://` domain is whitelisted.

Add any subdomain that you are currently using to test this app.

Comment: Unfortunately, my domain("my-project-name.firebaseapp.com") was added automatically in Authorized Domains  when i activated Authentication Provider(Phone) in Console...TT

Comment: I had to whitelist both www.mydomain.com and mydomain.com

Comment: Waited 2 days to figure it out. There was another option to define the domain inside Google Developer for firebase account and that was not working at all. Thanks

Comment: In Oct 2022 it's `Firebase Console` -> `Authentication` -> **`Settings`**-> `Authorized Domains`

Answer (score 15):

This error occurs because when Google send otp on Number then it match your website url and your firebase Authentication url is your domain or site address match then it send you otp otherwise error occour.

To resolve the error, go to firebase console.

1. Go firebase console.
2. Click Authentication.
3. Click SIGN-IN METHOD.
4. Scroll down and check Authorized domains.
5. Add your site address where you implement phone Authentication.

Comment: Thanks, This worked for me, I have updated the domain name in authorized domain list and captcha issue solved instantly

Comment: I added the domain in the authorized domains but still its not working any other information?

Answer (score 7):

You should follow in here:

**Note: The domain need to add both: https://www.exam.com and exam.com**

To resolve the error, go to firebase console.

1. Go firebase console.
2. Click Authentication.
3. Click SIGN-IN METHOD.
4. Scroll down and check Authorized domains.
5. Add your site address where you implement phone Authentication.

Answer (score 7):

For new firebase Dashboard

Go to Firebase > Select your Project > Authentication > Settings and under **domain** you will find **Authorise Domains**.

Input the domain you want to add and save

Answer (score 6):

Go to Firebase > Select your Project > Authentication > Sign in method > Scroll Down -> Add your domain under 'Authorize Domain' section.

Follow the photo instruction :

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can find your answer in this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44091221/6120430
Unfortunately, phone authentication using Firebase JS library will not work in a Cordova/Ionic...

Answer (score -1):

Add domain name in Firebase console => Authentication => Settings => Authorised domains => Add domain: See the screenshots for more details.

[Firebase Console Setting Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIaf8.jpg)