# Host match not found. Google firebase messaging

Tags: django, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging

[Error message hostmatch not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tm6sZ.png) 
[image]

I am buliding uber-like-delivery app using django. I just implemented the firebase messaging but each time i try to add a phone number so that it sends a verification code it gives me the error:

> Hostmatch not found

[image: Firebase Configs]

So please anyone with an idea on how i can solve this. I tried the whitelisting thing , it doesn't change anything or maybe its my code.

```
<!--Phone Number Input-->
<b class="text-secondary">Phone Number</b><br />
<div class="card bg-white mt-2 mb-5">
    <div class="card-body ">

        <div id="recaptcha-container"></div>

        <div id="get-code" class="input-group mb-3 {% if request.user.customer.phone_number %} d-none {% endif %}">
            <label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your phone number">
            </label>
            <div class="input-group-append">
                <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button">Send code</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="verify-code" class="input-group mb-3 d-none">
            <label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Verification code">
            </label>
            <div class="input-group-append">
                <button class="btn btn-success" type="button">Verify code</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="change-phone"
            class="input-group mb-3 {% if not request.user.customer.phone_number %} d-none {% endif %}">
            <label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" disabled value="{{ requeat.user.customer.phone_number }}">
            </label>
            <div class="input-group-append">
                <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button">Change</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>

    function onVerify(idToken) {
        var form = document.createElement("form");
        form.method = "POST";

        var element1 = document.createElement("input");
        element1.name = "id_token";
        element1.value = idToken;
        form.appendChild(element1);

        var element2 = document.createElement("input");
        element2.name = "action";
        element2.value = "update_phone";
        form.appendChild(element2);

        var element3 = document.createElement("input");
        element3.name = "csrfmiddlewaretoken";
        element3.value = "{{ csrf_token }}";
        form.appendChild(element3);

        document.body.appendChild(form);
        form.submit();

    }

    window.recaptchaVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('recaptcha-container', {
        'size': 'invisible'
    });

    $("#get-code button").on('click', function () {
        const phoneNumber = $("#get-code input").val();
        console.log(phoneNumber);

        firebase.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, window.recaptchaVerifier)
            .then((confirmationResult) => {
                // SMS sent. Prompt user to type the code from the message, then sign the
                // user in with confirmationResult.confirm(code).
                console.log(confirmationResult);
                window.confirmationResult = confirmationResult;

                $("#get-code").addClass("d-none");
                $("#verify-code").removeClass("d-none");

            }).catch((error) => {
                // Error; SMS not sent
                toast(error.message, 'error');
            });

    });

    $("#verify-code button").on('click', function () {
        const code = $("#verify-code input").val();

        confirmationResult.confirm(code).then((result) => {
            // User signed in successfully.
            const user = result.user;
            console.log(user.phoneNumber);



            user.getIdToken().then(function (idToken) {
                onVerify(idToken);
            });
        }).catch((error) => {
            // User couldn't sign in (bad verification code?)
            toast(error.message, 'error');
        });
    });

    $("#change-phone button").on('click', function () {
        $("#change-phone").addClass("d-none");
        $("#get-code").removeClass("d-none");
    })
</script>
```

Comment: I don't see any calls to the Firebase Cloud Messaging API in the code you shared. Are you sure the error is coming from that, and not from your **Authentication** calls. E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46578267/hostname-match-not-found-error-in-firebase-phone-authenticationwith-ionic#:~:text=Go%20to%20Firebase%20%3E%20Select%20your,under%20'Authorize%20Domain'%20section.&text=Show%20activity%20on%20this%20post.,-You%20can%20find

Comment: Thanks for your input from the whitelisted domains i discovered that i had all the domains including localhost but not the default IP of the local host. Thats why i was getting the error.