# How do you return a javascript object? it keeps throwing a "Converting circular structure to JSON"

Tags: javascript, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, inappbrowser

I am working on an Ionic app, and I need to use firebase's phone authentication, to use that, I have to use google's recaptcha, which doesn't work in Ionic apps, so...

I made a web page that held the code for rendering the reCaptcha, and used cordova's inAppBrowser to navigate to it from inside my app.

after hours, I got everything working, and finally got the "recaptchaVerifier" object, that you need to pass to  `firebase.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber,recaptchaVerifier)`
.

I just need to pass the "recaptchaVerifier" object from the inAppBrowser, to my ionic app, I tried everything, and got stuck on a simple javascript function that would "return recaptchaVerifier" and I would grab it in Ionic, but it kept giving me `Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON`
What do I do? I just need to pass that object so I can send the verification sms from my app and continue registration/signing in.

the code for the static site that renders the recaptcha from inside the inAppBrowser:

```
 <script>

    var recaptchaVerifier;

    function lol() {
        alert("done");
    };

    $(document).ready(function() {
        recaptchaVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('gre', {
            'size': 'invisible',
            'callback': lol
        });
        recaptchaVerifier.render();
    });

    function getIt() {
        console.log(recaptchaVerifier);
        return recaptchaVerifier;
    };

</script>
```

The code for opening the inAppBrowser and grabbing the recaptchaVerifier Object:

```
 var myInterval;
    var  myValue : firebase.auth.ApplicationVerifier ;
   const browser = this.inAppBrowser.create("https://demo.firebaseapp.com","_blank",
   {"location":"no",clearcache:"yes",clearsessioncache:"yes"});


   browser.on("loadstop").subscribe(x=>{
     myInterval = setInterval(function(){
       browser.executeScript({code:"getIt()"}).then(data=>{myValue = JSON.parse(data)});
     },200);
   });
   browser.on("exit").subscribe(x=>{
     clearInterval(myInterval);
     this.presentAlert("Test Alert",myValue,"OK");
     console.log("Adnan12 is error "+ myValue);
   firebase.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber("+123456789",myValue)
   .then(function (confirmationResult) {

     this.presentAlert("alert title","sms sent","ok");
    }).catch(function (error) {
   this.presentAlert("alert title","sms NOT sent","ok");
});
   });
```

Comment: Can you doublecheck the issue is on the line that attempts to grab an object? The script should work fine.

Comment: Not all JavaScript objects can be serialized as JSON.

Comment: @Dellirium , I checked and rechecked many times, does not work, always gives me the error "Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON"

Comment: @pointy , I dont want to serialize it, I just need a function to return that object, cant javascript return an object without serializing it? if not, what other option do I have?

Comment: javascript returns object like it returns anything else, with a return statement. That sort of error simply cannot happen at the return statement, check and tell us at what codeline does the error happen. The thing is there could be multiple reasons why your getit() function, when called from the code in the bottom doesn't give you the desired result, scope issues, event issues, etc. The way it is written above though works 100%, call it from the same script and see what you get in `console.log(getIt());`

Comment: @Dellirium i just tried console.log(getIt());
It is giving me the object, nice and clean.
But when I call getIt() from the app, outside the html page, it gives me that same annoying error

Comment: I tried adding @bojeil 's method : https://stackoverflow.com/a/44091221/775296
but I cant understand how to make a new applicationVerifier and add the info i captured in it.

Comment: @Eaves12 then it is not a 'javascript returning object' issue m8, it is outside of scope or unreachable for some other reason. I cannot help you there though since I do not know ionic. The script itself works and is good, so look elsewhere