# Ionic3 Firebase Phone Authentication JS SDK

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, ionic2, firebase-authentication

I was trying to integrate Ionic3 (Installable Native app) with firebase authentication with JS SDK without use of any plugin , On the web it seems to be working fine but when I install it on device It shows a captcha error showing please upgrade to supported browser to get a reCAPTCHA challenge , so is there any workaround to solve the captcha without using any plugins. I have also tried invisible captcha option but still gives some captcha error

Comment: Maybe [crosswalk](https://crosswalk-project.org/) could help

Comment: Could you please share code in which you load Firebase SDK?

Comment: Check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44081040/ionic2-authentication-firebase