# Repackage a reCAPTCHA token in a firebase.auth.ApplicationVerifier

Tags: android, cordova, firebase, firebase-authentication, recaptcha

**Firebase Phone Authentication in Angular and Cordova Android app with External Recaptcha Token.**

I am creating an application which requires **Phone authentication** through **Firebase**. The application is web-based in Angular, and wrapped in Cordova for Android and iOS. When running on the web-browser, all is working great. When wrapping in Cordova and running in a browser, all is still great. But when building the Android APK and running **on Android, the Phone Authentication doesn't work properly**, because the **ReCaptcha renderer fails** to load since the origin is "file:\\" on Android.

I searched a lot on the web, and it seems this is **[the only viable solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44091221/10312144)**

In this answer, I was able to follow steps 1, 2 and 3 to host the ReCaptcha on a website that the app redirects to, perform the ReCaptcha verification there and retrieve a ReCaptcha Token.

However in Step 4, it says the following:

> Parse the reCAPTCHA token from the deep link. Repackage it in a firebase.auth.ApplicationVerifier implementation.

**Is anyone able to help on how to Repackage a reCAPTCHA token in a firebase.auth.ApplicationVerifier ?**

I couldn't find a way to do it until now, any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Afterall I was able to achieve Firebase Authentication with Cordova on Android with no need to apply the complex workaroud mentioned.

I followed the steps [in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3tlSUMsEqAA) using cordova firebase plugin and it worked well, and did not require a ReCaptcha verification.